On the Peano Axioms (Set Theory)
According to Wolfram Math World, the Peano Axioms are as follows:

0 is a number
If x is a number, then the successor of x is a number
0 is not the successor of a number
Two numbers of which the successors are equal are themselves equal
If a set S of numbers contains zero and also the successor of every number in S, then every number is in S.

However, the Peano Axioms can be interpreted in another sense:

The null set is a set
If x is a set then the power set of x is a set
The null set isn’t the power set of a set
Two sets of which the power sets are equal are themselves equal
If a set S of sets contains the null set and also the power set of every set in S, then every set is in S.

Based on this interpretation/model of the Peano Axioms, does the power set of the set of natural numbers satisfy the Peano Axioms?

statement "5." in 'another sense' is weird/wrong, try to figure out why

Hint to @ac15's obervation.  Is S an element of S?

Notice that in the Peano Axioms, the set S, is itself not a Number, although it contains every number.

Since this is just basically a repost of your previous question, I'll just post a link to my previous answer, which is along the same lines as the comment by @ac15.

I must be missing something, but I'm having trouble proving that "the null set isn’t the power set of a set."

@DanChristensen Powerset of any set is nonempty, because every set is a subset of itself. So, at minimum, P(x) contains x.

It might be easier to see if you phrase it the other way, the Power Set of a set is never empty.

@Poscat I don’t see why it’s a bad thing. There are set theoretic models of the Peano axioms, so the OP is just wondering if this is a model of the axioms
